# Customization in Vuetify tab

Tags: vuejs3, vuetifyjs3, vuetify-tabs

I'm new to VueJS and using Vuetify. How can I get a Tab component like the image below? What I really want is to simply show only the selected tab button in the center, the other tab buttons should disappear. As I use the Next and Prev arrows, it should change the current tab, always leaving only the active tab button in the center and hiding the other tab buttons.

[image]